# I am not able to understand how new() operator is used in the following context. Can anyone explain me how?

Tags: c++, c++11

The code I referred is in the link -> http://upcoder.com/3/roll-your-own-vector
In this example, in the copyrange method, they are using new operator like in the below code.

```
  static void
copyRange(T* begin, T* end, T* dest)
{
    while(begin != end)
    {
        new((void*)dest) T(*begin);
        ++begin;
        ++dest;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how new() works in this context?

Can I write `new (dest) T(*begin);` instead of `new((void*)dest) T(*begin);` since dest is already a pointer to T. Why should I cast it back to `void*`?

Comment: Hey, I could use a bit more clarification. Can anyone help me with it. I've edited the question.

Comment: There are over 20 versions of [operator new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). To make sure we get the `void* operator new(std::size_t count, void* ptr);` version we want, it is customary to cast the pointer parameter to `void*`. Otherwise we just *might* end up with an unexpected user defined operator new for `T*`.